# Avise me an ADF component for jumping panels

Tags: layout, richfaces, oracle-adf

Please, advise me an adf layout component to obtain following behavior:

```
<af:__AdvisedComponent__>
<...panel_1...>
<...panel_2...>
</af:__AdvisedComponent__>
```

When window is wide enough (width may be parametrized) panels lay in horizontal layout:

```
___________ ___________
| panel_1 | | panel_2 |
```

And when user decreases window width the view must change to vertical layout:

```
___________
| panel_1 |
___________
| panel_2 |
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. I'm not asking for code, but for exact name of component or tag I can't find in library. In the worst case I need a designation that such behavior is unrealizable in ADF from a person who can demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no components for that, you can try use conditional layout EL Expression with Panel Group Layout but it'll be very messy.

I believe you should just create a Panel Group Layout to cover both of them and add media query tags in a custom css file by using the af:resource tag

Answer (score 0):

2 answers come to mind:
1. Use a panelGroupLayout manager and change it's HOrientation from vertical to horizontal at run time and refresh (not tried this)
2. Use a af:switcher component to show either of the two layout choices based on what is happening on the page.